# Segmentation fault on recursion function c++

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, binary-tree

I was working on Pre-order traverse Binary Tree algorithm. But I meet with Segmentation fault:11 error. The codes are shown as follow.

I want to know why this error happens. By the way, I have tried non-recursion algorithm `preorder()`，segmentation fault still happen.

The environment: 
macOS, clang-800.0.38

```
struct Node{
    char val;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

void preorder(Node *T){
    if(T!=NULL){
        cout << T->val;
        preorder(T->left);
        preorder(T->right);
    }
}

int main(){
    Node *T = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node *p = T;
    p->val = 'A';
    p->left = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->left->val = 'B';
    p->right = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->right->val = 'C'; 
    preorder(T);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: malloc won't zero-out the memory for you.  Which means, the `Node` malloc-ed could have non-NULL left and right so your `preorder()` will incorrectly traverse into invalid memory location.  As you are using C++, why don't you write a constructor for your class and use `new`, instead of using `malloc` ?

Comment: Both answers have pointed out the cause.  You could do self-diagnosis here in the future: https://segfault.stensal.com/a/e4e7lMyfNQ62slZH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `left` and `right` member variables of your nodes to null pointers.

---

Anyway, if you use C++, use C++ and not C constructs. This is an exemplary C++14 version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Node{
   Node(char a) : val(a) { };
   char val;
   std::unique_ptr<Node> left, right;
};

void preorder(Node* p) {
   if (p) {
      std::cout << p->val;
      preorder(p->left.get());
      preorder(p->right.get());
   }
}

int main() {
   auto root = std::make_unique<Node>('A');
   root->left = std::make_unique<Node>('B');
   root->right = std::make_unique<Node>('C');

   preorder(root.get());
}
```

Comment: sry for asking, but isn't this plain `c++11`??

Comment: being in the good position, to be able to use always the newest features. i lost track of the versions. thy for the answer =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is left and right of your child nodes are not initialized to NULL. Due to  previous value stored in that memory location the program is encountering non-null value in your `if(T!=nullptr)` statement and executing the if block.

```
struct Node{
    char val;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

void preorder(Node *T){
    if(T!=nullptr){
        cout << T->val;
        preorder(T->left);
        preorder(T->right);
    }
}

int main(){
    Node *T = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Node *p = T;
    p->val = 'A';
    p->left = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->left->val = 'B';
    p->left->left = nullptr;   //Initialize to NULL
    p->left->right = nullptr;  //Initialize to NULL
    p->right = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->right->val = 'C'; 
    p->right->left = nullptr;  //Initialize to NULL
    p->right->right = nullptr; //Initialize to NULL
    preorder(T);
    return 0;
}
```